# How to indicate that a function is executing which re-renders the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular I have loaded a page. After I press a button "Change" a function is called

```
ng-click = "changeFunction()"
```

in which the content of the page is re-evaluated and changes (the change is mostly in `{{textVariables}}` and images of the page).

If the content of the page being changed is less, this switch is fast enough to not be an issue. However if a lot of the content is being changed, the button appears pressed for an extended period of time, which gives the appearance that something in the page has broken (even though it has not, it is just taking time to re-evaluate the content).

How do I then modify my changeFunction() in the angular controller to mark a flag true when it starts changing and false when it finishes changing, so that I can use the flag to perhaps show the user something is happening?

To be clear, I am just asking for the javascript part of the code, the UI element I can design.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a straightforward addition:

```
changeFunction() {
  if (!this.saving) {
    this.saving = true;
  }

  // Your code here;

  // This is the last bit of the method:
  this.saving = false;
}
```

Then elsewhere in the controller (or the template) you can check for this.saving or (if you're using 'vm' in the template) vm.saving.

Comment: This was the first solution I tried, but the problem here is the function is executed first and the DOM is evaluated cumulatively at the end. Meaning vm.saving never really evaluates to true at the DOM level (unless there is something wrong in my understanding).